# Error When Importing to a for_each Resource

Tags: terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to import multiple AWS IAM policies and IAM roles to my tfstate files using a shell script to automate the import mechanism. It works fine when I was trying to import the IAM roles, but when I tried to import an IAM policy it seems that the imported state overwrite the previous import results and I always comes to:

```
Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on /project/iam_role.tf line 14, in resource "aws_iam_role" "roles":
│   14:         aws_iam_policy.policies["S3FullWithoutDelete"].arn,
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_iam_policy.policies is object with 1 attribute "IAMEnableMFA"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Here is an example of the command that I'm trying to run.

```
terraform import 'aws_iam_policy.policies["IAMEnableMFA"]' arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:policy/IAMEnableMFA
```

Here is the iam_policy.tf file configuration.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policies" {
  for_each = {
    "Billing-Organizations"          = "billing_organizations.json"
    "BillReadOnly"                   = "bill_readonly.json"
    "AccountAndTaxsettings"          = "account_and_tax.json"
    "S3FullWithoutDelete"            = "s3_full_without_delete.json"
    "ConsolidatedBillingForMOCB"     = "consolidated_billing_for_mocb.json"
    "Organizations"                  = "organizations.json"
    "CostExplorerAPI"                = "cost_explorer_api.json"
    "Invite_Account_To_Organization" = "invite_account_to_organization.json"
    "IAMEnableMFA"                   = "iam_enabled_mfa.json"
    "OrganizationsReadOnly"          = "organizations_read_only.json"
    "Modify_EC2_RI"                  = "modify_ec2_ri.json"
    "billing-upload-s3-cur"          = "billing_upload_s3_cur.json"
  }
  name   = each.key
  policy = file("${path.module}/policy/${each.value}")
  tags   = var.resource_tags
}
```

And this is the iam_role.tf file configuration.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "roles" {
  for_each = {
    "ADFS-Billing" = {
      "file" = "adfs_billing.json"
      "policy_arns" = [
        aws_iam_policy.policies["Billing-Organizations"].arn,
        aws_iam_policy.policies["Modify_EC2_RI"].arn,
        data.aws_iam_policy.policies["IAMFullAccess"].arn,
        data.aws_iam_policy.policies["Billing"].arn,
        data.aws_iam_policy.policies["ReadOnlyAccess"].arn,
        data.aws_iam_policy.policies["AWSSupportAccess"].arn,
        data.aws_iam_policy.policies["AWSCloudTrail_FullAccess"].arn,
        data.aws_iam_policy.policies["AWSBillingConductorFullAccess"].arn,
        aws_iam_policy.policies["S3FullWithoutDelete"].arn,
        aws_iam_policy.policies["AccountAndTaxsettings"].arn
      ]
    }
   # There are other similar items, but omitted for brevity
  }

  name                = each.key
  assume_role_policy  = file("${path.module}/trust_relationships/${each.value["file"]}")
  managed_policy_arns = each.value["policy_arns"]
  tags                = var.resource_tags
}
```

How can I import all of these policies to my tfstate file properly?